# Unable to load Info.plist error Xcode 10 under macOS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave

I got this error message while running my app from within Xcode and the Archived exported app do NOT execute under macOS 10.14

```
[default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
```

BTW, change Xcode's File -> Project Settings -> Build System to "Legacy Build System" does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an Xcode bug, it's a Mojave bug.

I met this error every seconds. No matter I open any app, all comes with this bug in the Console.

I can't use the settings in `System Prefrences - Security - Privacy - Accessibility` because I can't add anything to the list ( I'm sure I unlocked the panel )

And when I start Steam, it also cause this error ------ Then the Steam exits on it's own.

Seems it was due to the `CoreServices` or `LaunchServices`, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with my project - everything builds fine, but nothing show up except that error:

> Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)

It IS Mojave bug. Apple trying to fix this issue in the next versions of Xcode. For now, I recommend to just downgrade the IDE for 9.4.1 version and waiting for resolve. It was the only option worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not relevant but I had a similar issue today - XCode 10 + High Sierra.

Mine was an issue with the Fabric/Run script in the Build Phases window.  The error suggested it was a 'timing' issue.  I checked the box that said 'Run script only when installing' in the build phases window, and now my project builds and runs again.

[UPDATE]
My solution was found here:
[XCode 10 archive failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510579/xcode-10-command-line-building-archive-failed-with-fabric-info-plist-error)

Comment: sorry Carl, change to "Legacy Build System" does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

Apps linked against 10.14 (Mojave) need to add this key to their Info.plist

```
NSAppleEventsUsageDescription
```

Details on usage available here [Apple Developer Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/702/) and here [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109561).

Comment: "Apps can only provide one usage description. It is not possible to provide different usage descriptions for every target app..." https://www.felix-schwarz.org/blog/2018/08/new-apple-event-apis-in-macos-mojave

Comment: @ Cliff Ribaudo Please list a simple solution to make your reply as a complete answer, thank you.

Comment: More info on this over here: https://indiestack.com/2018/08/apple-events-usage-description/

Comment: While this might solve the **AppleEvents** issue, the other issue (`[default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)`) remained unsolved.

Comment: Sorry to downgrade the answer, but this does not explain well enough how to answer the question/solve the mentioned problem ("eGPUOverrides" log). I'll be happy to upgrade it again if you can complement the answer, and if it works (which doesn't seem to be the case right now).

Comment: Down voted because this appears to be completely irrelevant to the issue described here. The link to Apple Developer Forum solves a different issue, and just incidentally also mentions the same issue raised here but offers no explanation or solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

The very latest Beta of Mojave 10.14.4 Beta (18E194d) fixed it for me. Without changing anything in XCode the error is finally gone.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be resolved with the Public release of 10.14.4.  I was having the issue until yesterday using 10.14.3 Public release but after overnight update the issue is gone.

I have removed the various work around suggestions such as 'Build System Legacy' in XCode and NSAppleEventsUsageDescription, which didn't actually help in my case, and everything is still fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've got xcode 10.1 and mojave 10.14 and solve it by build to `Legacy Build System` (as you mentioned) but also when my app ran, it triggered the OS to open an accessibility window for that app. I removed the current app association with `-` and re-added it.