# Xcode 10 command-line building: Archive failed with Fabric Info.plist Error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, auto-build

I have Jenkins server for autobuilding iOS project that has two targets.
Project builds with command-line utility `xcodebuild`.

Full commands are

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace "Our project.xcworkspace"
    -scheme "First target"
    -configuration Release
    archive
    DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=TEAMCODE
    -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

and

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace "Our project.xcworkspace"
    -scheme "Second target"
    -configuration Release
    archive
    DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=TEAMCODE
    -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

Before I did update Xcode to version 10 it works perfectly. But after updating each time I see error

> error: Fabric: Info.plist Error
>
> Unable to process Info.plist at path /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Our_project-xxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Our project/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/First application.app/Info.plist
>   This could be a timing issue, make sure the Fabric run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved Our application.app from the location Xcode generated it. You can also add '$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)' as an "Input Files" dependency for your Fabric run script build phase.
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

After googling and reading error description I did open `Build phases` tab in Xcode and set up it (move `Run script` item to bottom, check `Run script only when installing` and add `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` to Input files and also remove empty `Run script` item).

Manual building from command line now works - it seems like problem solved. Even Jenkins did build first target! But secong target did not with same error.

I did open project, look Build phases tab and saw that `Run script` item moved above and new empty `Run script` appeared.
After that I did experiment: set up Build phases, rebuild project in Xcode GUI and saw that phases reordered again. So, it occurs during or after building.

How can I fix this bug?

Say, can I order build phases manually from command line? If yes, I just append row in Jenkins step.

In addition: this error appears only in command-line building. When I build project from Xcode GUI it always succeeds.

Answer (score 20):

I moved "Run Script" with crashlytics to the end after "Embed pods Frameworks" and "Copy pods Resources" and that helped[image]

Answer (score 19):

Okay, I got the solution form Fabrics.
For Xcode 10, add this path to the Input Files in Build phase in XCode
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

[image]

Comment: But I added it too:
"After googling and reading error description I did open `Build phases` tab in Xcode and set up it (move `Run script` item to bottom, check `Run script only when installing` and add `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` to Input files and also remove empty `Run script` item)."

Comment: Worked for me, when moving an old Xcode 10 project to Xcode 10.2.1 and having deleted the old derived data.

Comment: I had this problem and it turned out I was running the script too early. It's best run closer to last.

Answer (score 8):

I found crutch-like solution: select `Legacy Build System` at `File` -> `Workspace Settings` -> `Build System` in Xcode GUI.

Why this solution is bad? Because of:

- `Legacy Build System` is slower than `New Build System (Default)`.
- It's not Xcode setting but workspace. I.e. after cleaning workspace folder in Jenkins or some version control system actions will reset this setting to default, and non-working option will select again.

Comment: have you got another solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 6):

Solution to complete the setup of Crashlytics and/or Fabric using following:

1. Go to Build Settings
2. Search "Debug Information Format"
3. Change value of "Debug" from "DWARF" to "DWARF with dSYM File"
4. Build your project again.

Change "DWARF"

[image]

To "DWARF with dSYM File"

[image]

Comment: I already have `DWARF with dSYM File` for `Debug Information Format` option

Comment: @GeneralFailure Can you check with this, it may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53852817/3122406

Comment: @GeneralFailure Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Sorry, I can not check it now because I changed working project.

Comment: This worked for me. Looks like Fabric needs that dSYM file to detect and move forward. Thanks @BhavikModi

Answer (score 6):

I deleted derived data of the project and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 15.0:

move Run script item to bottom, check Run script only when installing and add $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH) to Input files

Comment: it might be helpful to phrase this as steps / bulletpoints

Answer (score 0):

Put `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` under `Input Files` in your `Build Phases` `Run Script`