# Crashalytics not working for xcode 10, iOS12

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

Crashlytics does not report crash event to Fabric for Xcode 10 or higher and iOS 12 or higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To report crash to Fabric from Xcode 10 and iOS 12 or higher

Step 1:

1. Go to Build Settings
2. Search "Debug Information Format"
3. Change value of "Debug" from "DWARF" to "DWARF with dSYM File"
4. Build your project again.

[image: Debug Information Format]

Step 2:

Set absolute path of Info.plist in "Input Files"
- Add/Change "Input Files" value in Run Script added for Fabric under "Build Phases"
- From "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)" To new path* "/Info.plist"

*new path: You can also get Info.plist path from Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File

[image: Plist Path]

Comment: what's up with the step 2? Why not use `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` ?

Comment: @Lukas1 Because, $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH) was not able to locate plist file run time and causing issues build with latest xcode.

Comment: ok but that must be related to something in your own setup, because for me it works without any issues.