# JavaFx Desktop application not Launching on Mac OS Mojave version 10.14

Tags: java, macos, javafx, macos-mojave

My Java Application is stoped launching on Mojave version 10.14.

Getting following error on Mac Console

Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
I am not using XCode.
This application is created using java1.7.0_76, JavaFx2.2.76_b13 and Netbeans 7.4 Ide.For making build or executable we use Ant script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load Info.plist error Xcode 10 under macOS 10.14 Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507950/unable-to-load-info-plist-error-xcode-10-under-macos-10-14-mojave)

Comment: are you running external GPU?
Please, provide more information:
Java Version +  (32 or 64 bits)

Comment: My Application is build using Jdk1.7.0_76, JavaFx2.2.76_b13 and Netbeans Ide. For building application and making executable we use Ant script. This application is successfully running till OSX High Sierra - 10.13.6. But after upgrading from 10.13 to 10.14 it stops launching and giving the above error on console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 7 supported JavaFx application is not running on Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628129/java-7-supported-javafx-application-is-not-running-on-mojave)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question several times.