# Java 7 supported JavaFx application is not running on Mojave

Tags: java, javafx, info.plist, macos-mojave

My application supported on:

```
Jdk1.7.0_76,  
JavaFx2.2.76_b13,   
Netbeans IDE,
```

Ant for building and creating installer.
Supported on Windows and Mac.

It's running successfully till High-Sierra

When I tried to run `.app` file on Mojave it is giving

> Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)

And when I tried to run jar file it gives following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Make sure the correct version of java is installed.

Comment: I have installed correct version. Yesterday I uninstall all the version of java and reinstall jdk1.7.0_76 version still my application is not launching.

Comment: This looks like a very common error when the JavaFx library isn't in the jdk path. Usually this occurs when using `openJDK` as that doesn't come prepacked with JavaFx. Can you confirm that you have the jfx libraries in the jdk path?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. JavaFx library is present in the JDK path here is the path of the library /⁨Library/⁨Java/⁨JavaVirtualMachines/⁨jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/⁨Contents/⁨Home⁩/⁨jre/⁨lib/jfxrt.jar

Comment: Hmm. The only other thing I can think of is the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is potentially incorrect. If that IS correct, then I have no idea what is wrong.