# Java 7 supported Application crashes on Mojave

Tags: crash, java-7, macos-mojave

My application supported on

jdk1.7.0_76
JavaFx2.2.76_b13
Netbeans IDE

It's running successfully till Mac-OSX-HighSierra.

When I tried to run this application on Mojave using Netbeans the application crashes and giving following error.

```
    Launching <fx:deploy> task from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
objc[8382]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java (0x1018244c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/./libjli.dylib (0x10b4f3480). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fff4200543b, pid=8382, tid=775
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [CoreFoundation+0x13f43b]  _CFRelease+0x434
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/rahulsharma/NetBeansProjects/CreatFXMLTst/hs_err_pid8382.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Java Result: 134
debug:
jfxsa-debug:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 7 supported JavaFx application is not running on Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628129/java-7-supported-javafx-application-is-not-running-on-mojave)

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing the exact same crash in Firefox (illegal instruction at that address), it's probably an issue in CoreFoundation:

[Firefox crashes @ CoreFoundation+0x13f43b](https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/signature/?product=Firefox&signature=CoreFoundation%400x13f43b)