# Xcode: Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)

Tags: xcode, info.plist

Whenever I start a new project (macOS Swift) in Xcode (latest versions of Xcode and Mac) I come across this error message:

> Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)

I create a new project, run it without having edited a single thing, and this message appears in the console.

Has anybody come across this issue before or have any suggestions as to how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load Info.plist error Xcode 10 under macOS 10.14 Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507950/unable-to-load-info-plist-error-xcode-10-under-macos-10-14-mojave)

Comment: Unfortunately, this page doesn't come to a solution for the Info.plist problem. It solves a problem people had with AppleEvents

Comment: I think it's benign.