# QLPreviewPanel not displaying image Swift OSX

Tags: swift, macos, quicklook

I'm trying to use QuickLook in OSX. There are several problems with my sample code:

1) It does not preview the image.

2) I get these errors:

> 2019-05-05 08:35:17.898276+0100 QuickLook[13561:1658693] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides) 2019-05-05
>   08:35:17.963612+0100 QuickLook[13561:1658651] [General]
>       -[QLPreviewPanel setDelegate:] called while the panel has no controller - Fix this or this will raise soon.   See comments in
>   QLPreviewPanel.h for
>       -acceptsPreviewPanelControl:/-beginPreviewPanelControl:/-endPreviewPanelControl:.
>   2019-05-05 08:35:17.963759+0100 QuickLook[13561:1658651] [General]
>       -[QLPreviewPanel setDataSource:] called while the panel has no controller - Fix this or this will raise soon.     See comments in
>   QLPreviewPanel.h for
>       -acceptsPreviewPanelControl:/-beginPreviewPanelControl:/-endPreviewPanelControl:.
>   2019-05-05 08:35:18.050123+0100 QuickLook[13561:1658651] [Layout]
>   Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints: (
>           "",
>           "",
>           "
>   (active)>",
>           "",
>           "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to
>   have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this
>   happens.  And/or, set a symbolic breakpoint on
>   LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE to catch this in the debugger.
>   2019-05-05 08:35:18.050436+0100 QuickLook[13561:1658651] [Layout]
>   Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints: (
>           "",
>           "",
>           "
>   (active)>",
>           "",
>           "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to
>   have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this
>   happens.  And/or, set a symbolic breakpoint on
>   LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE to catch this in the debugger.

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

class ViewController: NSViewController,  QLPreviewPanelDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        if let sharedPanel = QLPreviewPanel.shared()
        {
            sharedPanel.delegate = self
            sharedPanel.dataSource = self
            sharedPanel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func previewPanel(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "myimage.jpg")
        return url as QLPreviewItem
    }
}
```

Please could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the same issue: [swift QLPreviewPanel crash — NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363591/swift-qlpreviewpanel-crash-nsconstraintbasedlayoutvisualizemutuallyexclusivec)?

Comment: No it's different. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it different? Did you try the suggestions in the errors?

Comment: See [Unable to load Info.plist error Xcode 10 under macOS 10.14 Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507950/unable-to-load-info-plist-error-xcode-10-under-macos-10-14-mojave)

Comment: Take a look at sample code [QuickLookDownloader](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009082). It made me understand how to use `QLPreviewPanel`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the constraints errors but I can't. I get other weird errors, exceptions and warnings but no complaints about constraints.